# to change format of date in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have got date store in my database in datetime format,whereas in my view page I need to display date in different format.

My current query in model is-

```
function get_date($id)

{

 $query=$this->db->query("select `created_time` from `comments` where        `post_id`=$id");
$query2= $query->result_array();
$date=$query2['0']['created_time'];

 return $date;   
        }
```

result on view page: `2013-09-10 07:22:00`
which is correct but what I want is:

```
10 sep 13
```

now can anyone please help me how to change the result to this format.

Comment: This has been asked numerous times here. Look to the right ---> See?

Comment: @zaya **You're going to get no where with that attitude.** Don't expect people to help you if you can't be bothered to search, and don't be a dick to the people that do help you.

Comment: ohh..m extremely sorry..thnaks fr reply ll try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert your date into a unix timestamp, and then use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format it how you want:

```
<?php
    $date = '2012-02-06 22:20:37';
    $date = date('j M y', strtotime($date));
    var_dump($date); //6 Feb 12
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/5Nphu7fT)

And if you absolutely want it lowercase, just surround it by [`strtolower`](http://www.php.net/strtolower).